# Lost attributes when updating EF .edmx file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an edmx file with some domain partial classes, but i need to manually put the  the `[Key]` attribute on the representing primary key of the class.

Everytime i need to update the model classes within the database, the edmx file and its classes are recreated and i lost this attribute.

I remove the `OnModelCreating()` method too, and when the edmx updates the method is created again, so i need to go and remove it by hand.

How can i prevent it?
Thanks

Comment: So then don't put it into the generated code. What's the problem?

Comment: Is "Key" retained if you set it in the diagram rather than in the generated code?
I'm not sure what you mean by "commented".  Do you mean you removed it or added your own comments?

Comment: @Adam47 Commented i mean, remove it. ill edit the op.

Comment: @Adam47 if i go to the edmx diagram, i can see the `entity Key` overthere. but even like this, i need to put the parameter hardcode in the property. If i dont, it generates an error

Comment: You probably should just leave the OnModelCreating method alone.  If you really are bothered by it, you can edit the code gen template.<br />
As for the Key, perhaps you should delete the table from your model and refresh from the DB, then set the key (if it can't be discovered in the DB).<br />  Don't change the generated code.